# Cierre inesperado del programa al leer datos de usuario

Tags: c, lista, punteros, scanf

Estoy estudiando listas enlazadas y cuando ejecuto mi código se cierra cuando ingreso el nombre:

```
typedef struct HS{
    int semana, horas, salario;
}HS;

typedef struct datos{ 
    char nombre[50];
    int dia, mes, anio;
    HS HS[5];
}datos;

typedef struct Nodo{
    datos datos;
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
}Nodo;

int main() {
    datos *datos;
    datos=NULL;

    printf("\nINGRESE EL NOMBRE: ");
    scanf("%s", datos->nombre);
    printf("\nINGRESE LA FECHA: ");
    printf("\tDIA: ");
    scanf("%d", &datos->dia);
    printf("\tMES: ");
    scanf("%d", &datos->mes);
    printf("\tANIO: ");
    scanf("%d", &datos->anio);
    
    printf("%s\n", datos->nombre);
    printf("%d - %d - %d\n", datos->dia,datos->mes,datos->anio);
}
```

Además, no solo ocurre con el nombre, también con el día, mes y año.

Comment: sin ser experto, datos es null.. donde queres que guarde si no alocas el espacio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resumen**

> El programa se encarga de almacenar los datos de un empleado, y luego mostrarlo. Utiliza una estructura `tipoDato` para almacenar los datos del empleado, una estructura `tipoNodo` para almacenar los datos de la lista y `tipoHS` para almacenar los datos de la hora de trabajo.

**Explicación**

> - Primeramente, por buenas prácticas al momento de trabajar estructuras, asignamos `tipoNombre` al finalizar nuestra estructura, en donde `Nombre` representará el nombre que le definimos a la estructura.
> - Estos `tipoNombre` que acabamos de crear, los usaremos para definir una estructura ya definida dentro de otra estructura.
> - También por su parte, creamos los tipos que se usaran para crear nuevos objetos en main o cualquier otra función, estas estarán definidas para recibir una dirección en memoria. Lo definimos con `typedef tipoNombre *NOMBRE`.
> - Al momento de inicializar un nuevo objeto, primero debemos reservar un espacio en memoria para dicho objeto. Lo inicializamos con `NOMBRE objeto = (NOMBRE)malloc(sizeof(tipoNombre))`
> - Una vez reservado el espacio en memoria, debemos verificar si se reservó correctamente. Para ello, usamos un condicional `if` que verifica que dicho objeto sea diferente de NULL `if (objeto != NULL)`
> - En caso de que `si` se haya reservado el espacio en memoria correctamente, ya podemos hacer todas las operaciones necesarias para trabajar con nuestro objeto. `Sino`, mostraremos un mensaje que indique que la operación no fue exitosa.

**Solución**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct HS{
    int semana, horas, salario;
} tipoHS;

typedef struct dato{ 
    char nombre[50];
    int dia, mes, anio;
    tipoHS HS[5];
} tipoDato;

typedef struct Nodo{
    tipoDato datos;
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
} tipoNodo;

typedef tipoHS *HS;
typedef tipoDato *DATO;
typedef tipoNodo *NODO;

int main() {
    DATO dato = (DATO)malloc(sizeof(tipoDato));
    if (dato != NULL) {
        printf("\n\tINGRESE EL NOMBRE: ");
        scanf("%s", dato->nombre);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n\tINGRESE LA FECHA: ");
        printf("\n---------------------------\n");
        printf("\n\tDIA: ");
        scanf("%d", &dato->dia);
        printf("\n\tMES: ");
        scanf("%d", &dato->mes);
        printf("\n\tANIO: ");
        scanf("%d", &dato->anio);
        
        printf("%s\n", dato->nombre);
        printf("%d - %d - %d\n", dato->dia,dato->mes,dato->anio);
    } else {
        printf("\n\tNo hay espacio en memoria disponible");
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias bro, eso fue de mucha utilidad